# How to change the value of [(value)] from typescript in a dropdown In angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a dropdown menu in which I want to be able to set the value of the item and let the user see it automatically (from typescript) rather than him choosing it manually (not always but in a specific case)

values can be changed from *typescript* with `[(ngModel)]` but I have to use `[(value)]` as in the code below:

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select placeholder="My devices" [(value)]="DeviceId">
   <mat-option>Choose</mat-option>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let device of devices" ngDefaultControl [value]="device.ID"
          (click)="exec(device.STATUS)">
          {{DEVICE.LABEL}}
     </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
```

If the user chooses the value he want, the code works perfectly as I want, but at some point, *I need to automatically display a certain item from this dropdown automatically without user intervention*

Comment: `[(ngModel)]`...

Comment: i cant because I need also to change it based on dropdown current item..

Comment: how do you initialise `DeviceId` in you ts?

Comment: Please find sample code :
<mat-select [(value)] ="selectedUserId" (selectionChange) = "onChange($event.value)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.id">
        {{user.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
In typescript file give selectedUserId.

Comment: @NidhinJoseph DeviceId: number;

Comment: if device.ID is number  eg: DeviceId = 4 , if device.ID is string  eg : DiviceId = "test"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to init the value with the ID which you need to set the dropdown. Check this [fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-rzxk18)

**TS**

```
selectedValue: string = 'id1';
selectedValue2: string;
```

**HTML**

```
<form>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Clients" [(value)]="selectedValue" name="food" (change)="changeClient($event.value)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let client of clients" [value]="client.id">
        {{client.clientName}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Clients" [(value)]="selectedValue2" name="food" (change)="changeClient($event.value)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let client of clients" [value]="client.id">
        {{client.clientName}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

</form>

<p> Selected value: {{selectedValue}} </p>
<p> Selected value: {{selectedValue2}} </p>
```

Comment: Thanks :D Did the job!

Comment: @TheCondorIV Perfect!